# PHP: set variable to infinity

Tags: php

I am wondering if I can set a variable to infinity, and if not what the best way to achieve my problem is. Take my function below:

```
public function seekValue($value, $column = null, $limit = null) {
  $this->connect('rb');
  $results = array();
  while (!feof($this->_pointer)) {
      $data = explode($this->_config->delimiter(), fgets($this->_pointer, 1024));
      if(!is_null($column)) {
          if ($data[$this->_config->columns($column, "string")->index()] == $value)
              array_push($results, $this->formatRow($data));
      } else {
          if (in_array($value, $data))
              array_push($results, $this->formatRow($data));
      }
  }
  $this->disconnect();
  switch (count($results)) {
      case 0;
          return false;
      case 1;
          return $results[0];
      default;
          return $results;
  }
}
```

I set `$limit = null` in the function parameter list, however I later want to use `$limit` in my while loop like so `while (!feof($this->_pointer) && count($results) < $limit)` incase the user decides to pass an integer to it.

If this was the case I could do this:

```
if (!is_int($limit)) {
  $limit = infinity;
}
```

To say that if `$limit` is not set run infinite times.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: umm infinite loops???????  BLASPHEMY!!!!!!!!

Comment: @LaurenceBurke it's not an infinite loop, it has two conditions I just want to make one of the conditions infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just adapt the condition:

```
while (!feof($this->_pointer) && ( ($limit === NULL) || (count($results) < $limit)) )
```

Answer (score 89):

Just to answer the original question:

Yes you can set a variable to infinity by assigning `INF`

```
$x = INF;
var_dump($x > 10000); // bool(true)
var_dump($x - 100); // float(INF)
```

Comment: `INF` was just what I needed.

Comment: It's very disappointing that some questions never get their real answers :) but not this one, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not...

```
while (!feof($this->_pointer) && (is_null($limit) || count($results) < $limit))
```

This way if it isn't null is only when it will evaluate && count($results) < $limit

Comment: This will fail when `$limit` is `NULL` at least; the whole expression will evaluate to `FALSE`.